# React - Eslint - Camel camel case props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, camelcasing

I have a question about a standard eslint and camel case.
I have a redundant error on this type of code.

```
const response = yield call(currentAccount, localStorage.getItem('auth_token'))
  console.log(`RESPONSE ${JSON.stringify(response)}`)


  if (response) {
    const { id, email, first_name, last_name, name } = response

    yield put({
      type: 'user/SET_STATE',
      payload: {
        id,
        name,
        email,
        authorized: true,
        lastname: last_name,
        firstname: fist_name
      },
    })
  }
```

> Line 53:  Identifier 'first_name' is not in camel case  camelcase

How can I fix this error without disabling esLint on this type of formatting ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think it can be fixed if you use camel case syntaxes. instead of `first_name` try `firstName` and check. Or you want forcibly off then checkout this doc https://eslint.org/docs/rules/camelcase#ignoredestructuring-true

Comment: You can rename when you destructure: `const { first_name: firstName } = response;`.

Comment: Oh, thanks jonrsharpe, I was doing the opposite earlier.

Comment: How do you expect to fix it without disabling it other than using camel case!? You can disable it for the file, a section, or just the line if you want

Answer (score 2):

You can assign different variable names when destructuring:

```
const { id, email, first_name: fistName, last_name: lastName, name } = response
```

Answer (score 1):

In your file you can add a comment like

```
/*eslint camelcase: ["error", {allow: ["first_name"]}]*/
```

Or you can configure camelcase rule in your .eslintrc

```
camelcase: ["error", {allow: ["first_name"]}]
```